# JavaScriptSerializer to escape chars

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extend strings and create a simple function that makes the string "JSON safe".

```
public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    return serializer.Serialize(obj);
}
```

But when I run the testcode:

```
string msg= _rep.GetResource("Delete_Confirm").ResourceValue.ToJSON();
```

It seems to add extra " around the string like this:

""Are you sure you want to delete \"Helo KittY\"?""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the output is correct: a json string is enclosed in double quotes.

The first double quote you see comes from your programming environment, it means this is a string in C#.

The second double quote is a real double quote char and it means start of a json string.

same goes for the two doble quotes at the end.

Hope this helps